# How to increase the size of the floating action button according to screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an application where I need to implement a floating action button. Also, I need to increase or decrease the size of the of the button, according to screen size.

Below is my floating action button code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="#2e2745"
        android:tint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

I tried to changed the size normally from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, but it wasn't reflecting at all.

Screen sizes above 6 inches, the floating button is looking really small and I have no idea how to change the size according to screen sizes.

Am I doing something wrong here??

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the getWidth and getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

now you has the Display size you can make width grammatically

```
FloatingActionButton btn=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/20, height/30)); //as you want
```

Comment: please replace new LinearLayout.LayoutParams in my code it was LinearLayout that contain FloatingButton i think you put in RelativeLayout so use new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()

Comment: don't forget to show all your xml code :) to see it myself and check it for u